# Word 2013 Automated Page number calculation

Tags: ms-word, word-2013

I want to write the current page number of a page that contains a picture as text. and I want it to be updated if the page number changes.
Example: 
Picture1 is on page 1. 
On page 2 I'll write something like "look at my picture1 on page 1".
Then I add text at the beginning of page 1.
So Picture1 moves to page 2 and my text moves to page 3.

Now, I want to read on page 3 "look at my picture1 on page2".
Is it possible to generate a page number of a picture by using field functions?

Comment: The first thing I need to know to do this is: How can I get the page number of a specific picture?

Comment: It's a pity that no MS-Word expert can tell me how to let word calculate the page number of a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I solved my problem by using cross-references.